# Add a new column for color code from red to green based on the increasing value of Opportunity in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame and I wanted to generate a new column for colour codes which stars from red for the least value of **Opportunity** and moves toward green for highest value of **Opportunity**

My Data Frame -

```
State       Brand       DYA  Opportunity    

Jharkhand   Ariel     0.15   0.00853    
Jharkhand   Fusion    0.02   0.00002
Jharkhand   Gillett   0.04   -0.0002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the color range from red to green you can use matplotlib [`color maps`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#diverging), more specifically, the `RdYlGn`. But before applying the color mapping, first, you need to normalize the data in the `Opportunity` column between 0 and 1. Then, from here you can encode the data to a color code in any away way you see appropriate. As an example, here I'm using Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function with the `rbg2hex` with the intention of grabbing the CSS value that represents the color mapping used in the `Opportunity` column.

```py
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.colors import rgb2hex

# df = Your original dataframe

cmapR = cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
norm = Normalize(vmin=df['Opportunity'].min(), vmax=df['Opportunity'].max())

df['Color'] = df['Opportunity'].apply(lambda r: rgb2hex(cmapR(norm(r))))

dstyle = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cmapR, subset=['Opportunity'])
dstyle.to_html('sample.html')
```

[image: df_color_coded]

Comment: Thanks and appreciated your help